# Magento 2 token integration error

Tags: magento2.2, api, rest-api, token

I can able to get token from http://example.com/magento2/rest/V1/integration/admin/token with Username & Password.

Using this token, I can request product details on http://example.com/magento2/rest/V1/products/:sku and get stock level are working.

When I try to get a order details, I am getting error like:

```
"message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
"parameters": 
    "resources": "Magento_Sales::sales"
```

When I try to get a customer details, I am getting error like:

```
"message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
"parameters": 
    "resources": "Magento_Customer::customer"
```

I can access only functions which is ***vendor/magento/module-moduleName/etc/webapi.xml*** with **resource ref="anonymous"**.

Rest of them I am having same error **"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources"**.

How can able to access all magento core function through rest api?

Comment: I copied this magento to new temporary server. Everything working fine. I am wondering what is wrong with my server. I can able to access all modules I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are able to access only that api which can be accessed anonymously. Now you are accessing a api which need a authentication key/access token to assure that you are a registered customer who is accessing such api's. So for generating you have to generate a access token using below api :

> {base_url}/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

this is a post type api, so you have to pass the username and password in the body,

```
{
"username":"{your_username}",
"password":"{password}"
}
```

and hit it, you will get a access token like this :

```
"6fomgh65em5jaivxqllorc50h2gqrhhe"
```

Now you have to use this access token in the api you are currently trying to access : In Postman -> go to header and in key = Authorization and in value = Bearer {your generated token} and hit **SEND**

DONE, That's All.

Comment: But this way will limit me from accessing all modules. Doesn't it?

Comment: no, in this way you can access all the api's using token which need customer token, or the api's which have set <resource ref="self" />.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of authentication available in magento 2.
One is via admin another is via customer.
You can use below api to get the authenticated token which will be used to run all api having  ref="self".

```
{base_url}/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
{base_url}/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```

Your request will be of POST type and param will be

```
{
"username":"{your_username}", 
"password":"{password}"
}
```

You have to use your admin login credentials for admin auth token or customer login credentials for customer token.

After getting the authentication token, you need to pass it while calling the api in basic authorisation

```
Authorization : Bearer cy50YW5kb25AaGVhbHRoY29hdXN0cmFsaWEuY29tLmF1OmhlYWx0aGNvMjAxNw==
```

something like above

Comment: My authentication is working fine, problem with my server.

Comment: anywhere else I can help you?

Comment: this seems to work for me

Comment: i am trying to use newly created token on (rest/V1/inventory/source-items) API but it only works if i define token as static, if i generate a new token at run time and pass in API then it gives authorized error... can you please guide

Answer (score 0):

You will get customer order by getting access token by using

```
http://example.com/magento2/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

with customer username & Password.

After that By using that access token You get customer order because this api only accessible for authenticate  customer.

Answer (score 0):

I updated whole server including kernel then I rebooted. Now it is working fine.